# Whether all objects which are not manually disposed be automatically disposed when program terminates?

Tags: c#, multithreading, dispose

Objects like FileStream, CryptoStream etc ...
Or I must manually dispose them.

I'm using Thread.IsBackground = true to terminate my working thread when user clicks on form close button.

Comment: Sounds like you forgot to close your previous question.

Answer (score 7):

Let's break that down into multiple questions:

> Will operating system resources such as file handles be automatically closed when my program terminates?

Generally speaking, yes. The operating system will automatically close all resources associated with the process when the process is destroyed.

> Suppose I have non-operating-system resources, like database connections. Will my application automatically send a message to the database saying that the connection is closed?

Not necessarily. However, the database should be written to be robust in the face of a flaky client.

> Should I clean up my resources even though I don't need to?

In a "normal" shutdown, yes. Suppose you have a resource leak in the future. It is going to be a lot easier to find the leak if you've had good discipline and always release your resources when you're done with them. Shut down your program in an orderly fashion.

In an "emergency" shutdown, just shut down as soon as possible. If the program is going down because of some fatal error, trying to clean up might just make it worse. Don't spend time sweeping the floors before the building collapses.

Comment: In general terms, an unmanaged resource is something which an object has asked *some outside entity* to do on its behalf until such time as it's told that its services are no longer needed.  Sometimes, the "outside entity" will be entirely contained within the application; sometimes, the outside entity will be the operating system.  In either of those cases, once the program is shut down the resources will be released.  It's entirely possible, however, that the entity may be something that the operating system knows nothing about, in which case the OS won't know how to clean it up.

Answer (score 3):

> Whether all objects [...] be automatically disposed when program terminates?

Yes. Ultimately all unmanaged resources are allocate from the OS (Windows) and when a process terminates, all its resources are freed. But that does not mean that all your `Dispose()` methods will be called, you have no guarantees on them. So don't put anything vital there.

Comment: Not all unmanaged resources are allocated from the OS.  If for example a program uses a connection-based protocol over UDP [may be logical in cases where it wouldn't make sense to retransmit dropped packets], the OS may have no way of knowing what sort of packet to send to let the far end know that its connection has "died".  Such connections could remain open indefinitely unless or until the far end eventually times out after not hearing anything for a long time.

Answer (score 0):

All object will automatically be disposed if not disposed manually....at an indeterminate time in the future.

Assuming they are built correctly.

Answer (score 0):

There are instances where the finalizers will *not* be run, for example if an exception is thrown from a finalizer, or if something calls [`Environment.FailFast()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms131100.aspx).

So it's certainly *not* something you can rely on.

You might also want to add this to the end of your `Main()` method:

```
GC.Collect();
GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
```

However, I think that any code that relies on this is *broken*.